# Omniauth facebook request friends uid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, omniauth

I am a rails newbie and I have followed Railscasts Episodes 235 and 236 regarding logging in with Omniauth. I have made it so a user can connect with Facebook and it grabs his email and his uid. However, i would like to grab his friends uid too. What i would like is a feature on my application so users can see their friends, from Facebook, who are using my application too. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You might also want to check out this gem: https://github.com/appoxy/mini_fb

Answer (score 0):

Hey Jake, I think this is what you need: https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=[your access token]

Read more here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ and scroll down to Connections