# Cross check if Facebook friend has signed into your app before

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, omniauth

I have a rails app that uses omniauth for Facebook login. I also use fb_graph to get the user's friends list. Instead of displaying ALL of the current_user's friends, I only want to display his friends who have used my app before.

The way I am thinking of doing this is adding a field to my user model that I can check in the view that I display the friends from. So for example

```
graph_user = FbGraph::User.me(current_user.oauth_token)
@friends = graph_user.friends
```

in the controller. Then in the view I can have:

```
@friends.each do |friend|
- if User.find_by_uid(friend.uid)
# display that friend
```

unfortunately, 'friend' doesn't have a uid but users who are authenticated obviously do. Is there something I can request from Facebook upon creating a new user, maybe email?, that I can check later against 'friend.'

Would checking email be ok? Currently we don't request email from Facebook login, but if I did, I don't think `friend.email` would allow me to collect that either, would it? What is a better way?

EDIT: I found [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091424/omniauth-facebook-request-friends-uid?rq=1) that says I can grab access tokens from friends or something, but I don't really understand, maybe someone could shed some light or point me to a tutorial?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use **fql** directly to get the friends who use the app. I'm not sure how to use fql in ruby but this post might help you- [Facebook FQL Query with Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178590/facebook-fql-query-with-ruby)

The query to get the friends who use the app-

```
SELECT uid FROM user WHERE is_app_user=1 AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

([user](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) table)